# How to "move" the document root up one level to the public directory?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, zend-framework

I copy the rewrite code from this [post](http://www.alberton.info/zend_framework_mod_rewrite_shared_hosting.html#.VRwyefnF98E) for Zend.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

The idea of it is to move the document root up one level to the public directory **without touching or modifying the virtual host file**.

So I tested it on a dummy project on my localhost just to see if it works on my local machine. **But it does not**. I still have to click on the public folder to see the web content.

This is my directories,

```
.htaccess
public/
   .htaccess
   index.php
```

index.php,

```
<?php

// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();
```

And I tested it on my live server as well. The rewrite code does not move the document root up one level to the public directory at all.

Any ideas what I have missed?

I tested on my Zend (Zend 2) project and it does not work too. And I still have to click on the public folder to see the web content.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

content of /public/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

I have to use this url to see the web page,

```
http://{localhost}/a-project/public/
```

instead of,

```
http://{localhost}/a-project/
```

It is the same on the live server, I have to use

```
http://my-website.com/public/
```

instead of,

```
http://my-website.com/
```

I thought that .htaccess in the root can move the document root up one level to the public directory **without touching or modifying the virtual host file**, but **it cannot** obviously...

Comment: Can you show content of `/public/.htaccess`? Also clarify what URLs are not working?

Comment: @anubhava please see my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule in `DocumentRoot` .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not upload project in `public_html` directory. you should upload your project to parent directory and rename your `public` directory to `public_html`.

Be care in some servers the document root is not `public_html`. it could be something like `www`, `htdocs`, ..

This separation is for more security, you force users to send request just with `index.php` and they can't access to parent directory and run scripts directly.

*you can also use `.htaccess`, but i don't recommend it

Comment: `This separation is for more security` I totally agree with this. `you can also use .htaccess, but i don't recommend it` so is it **not secure** then if use `.htaccess` to “move” the document root up one level to the public directory?

Comment: I want to use `.htaccess` in root of my app because some servers don't have `public_html`, `www`, or `htdocs` - if you ever heard about one.com

Comment: if you forward all requests to public folder you have protected your website from many attacks, but some security issues may remain if .htaccess  not configured correctly. for example in some case attackers can find site structure (directories) and guess your framework.

Comment: if you know how to configure secure htaccess, you can do it, but if you have no enough knowledge, it is better to change your host

Comment: Thanks! that makes sense. How can I configure a secure htaccess? any site or tutorial that I can pick it up from?

Comment: you can read `.htaccess` of any standard `cms` like joomla. most of these `cms` change document root with `.htaccess` for easy installation